# Will an SNES (US) work in Europe (Romania) or do I a need PAL version?

Tags: snes

Will an SNES (US) work in Europe (Romania) or do I a need PAL version? (Why?) (Note: I will use AV cables.)

Answer (score 3):

If you Google your problem, you can find many people with your same issue.

It seems to be possibile, but the main problem is that the *NTSC* SNES is expecting **110V** while the European power will be **220V-230V** and that's not good for it. So you may need a power supply or a kind of transformer.

Another problem is that the 2 consoles run with different *vertical frequencies*: NTSC has 60 Hz, PAL has 50Hz. (See [here](http://www.ebay.com/gds/difference-with-PAL-and-NTSC-in-super-nintendo-/10000000008571429/g.html))

Of course you also need a TV that supports NTSC input, and an American SNES will need American cartridges, too.

Check these links for futher info: [Regional lockout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Nintendo_Entertainment_System#Regional_lockout), [SpeedDemosArchive](https://forum.speeddemosarchive.com/post/running_ntsc_consoles_in_europe.html), [NintendoAge](http://www.nintendoage.com/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=8&threadid=92523) and [DigitPress](http://forum.digitpress.com/forum/showthread.php?127262-Importing-an-american-SNES-to-Europe-(Norway)).

Comment: NTSC and PAL is only for RF port or is also for A/V ?

Comment: As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Nintendo_Entertainment_System#Casing) states: All versions incorporate a plug for a power supply and a Nintendo-proprietary "MULTI OUT" A/V connector on the back. The MULTI OUT connector can output composite video, S-Video and RGB signals, as well as RF with an external [RF modulator](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/systems/supernes/hook_rftotv_snn.jsp).